# Finding file's size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsfilemanager, filesize

In my iPhone app I am using the following code to find a file's size. Even though the file exists, I am seeing zero for the size. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *URL = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XML/Extras/Approval.xml"];

NSLog(@"URL:%@",URL);
NSError *attributesError = nil;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&attributesError];

int fileSize = [fileAttributes fileSize];
```

Comment: Weird, with your code, I can get the filesize correctly, what was the problem?

Answer (score 130):

Try this;

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&attributesError];

NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
```

Note that the fileSize won't necessarily fit in an integer (especially a signed one) although you could certainly drop to a long for iOS as you'll never exceed that in reality. The example uses long long as in my code I have to be compatible with systems with much larger storage available.

Comment: Xcode 4.5+ one-liner: `long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue]`.

Comment: Better be `unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil][NSFileSize] unsignedLongLongValue]` because [`NSFileSize` is an **`unsigned`** `long long`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW2).

Comment: Can be written even shorter: `unsigned long long size = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil].fileSize`

Comment: You can't send the URL as the Path parameter. You need to send `[URL path]`

Answer (score 10):

One liner in Swift:

```
let fileSize = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(fileURL.path!)[NSFileSize]!.longLongValue
```

Comment: Updated for Swift 3: `let fileSize = try (FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path)[.size] as! NSNumber).uint64Value` _or_ `let fileSize = try (FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path) as NSDictionary).fileSize()`

Comment: With Swift error handling.... `let fileSize = (try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path))?[.size] as? Int ?? 0`

Answer (score 8):

If you have a `URL` (`NSURL`, not a `String`), you can get the file size without a `FileManager`:

```
 let attributes = try? myURL.resourceValues(forKeys: Set([.fileSizeKey]))
 let fileSize = attributes?.fileSize // Int?
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.x**

```
do {
    let fileSize = try (FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath) as NSDictionary).fileSize()
            print(fileSize)
    } catch let error {
            print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the file size in **MB**
Try This code for **swift**

```
func getSizeOfFile(withPath path:String) -> UInt64?
{
    var totalSpace : UInt64?

    var dict : [FileAttributeKey : Any]?

    do {
        dict = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: path)
    } catch let error as NSError {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    if dict != nil {
        let fileSystemSizeInBytes = dict![FileAttributeKey.systemSize] as! NSNumber

        totalSpace = fileSystemSizeInBytes.uint64Value
        return (totalSpace!/1024)/1024
    }
    return nil
}
```