# How to get the QLPreviewView's content size?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quicklook

I would like to know how I can get the `QLPreviewView` content size? It seems that the API doesn't have any methods to get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QLPreviewView` won't give you that.

But since you are supposed to give QuickLook a path to reach files, you can get yourself size of them with file manager.

[Take a look at this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743856/finding-files-size) for example.