# How to select multiple videos from album in swift?

Tags: swift

I need to select the multiple videos from albums and should know the size of each video. I am trying to use Gallery but it shows both photos and videos. In my case, I need to restrict to only videos.

```swift
@IBAction func gallery(_ sender: Any) {        
    let gallery = GalleryController()
    gallery.delegate = self
    present(gallery, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use picker to select multiple videos from gallery, use this pod.
https://github.com/opalorange/OpalImagePicker

Comment: I cannot see the restriction to the OpalImagePicker that to select only videos

Comment: imagePicker.allowedMediaTypes = Set([PHAssetMediaType.video]). you can specify media asset of your choice with this code snippet.

Comment: with this library you can select multiple videos, mixed assets, multiple images whatever you want.

Comment: Can I know the size of each video?

Comment: search a bit around here, you will find some solution. also explore the library as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262791/how-to-get-image-file-size-in-swift

Comment: Is this  the method where the video URL gets stored?   func imagePicker(_ picker: OpalImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImages images:  [UIImage]) {} (or)     func imagePicker(_ picker: OpalImagePickerController, didFinishPickingExternalURLs urls: [URL]) {}

Comment: if you are accessing from external source then second one will be use otherwise there is a method that return array of assets which will return array of selected assets from gallery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206698/discussion-between-sravya-gajavalli-and-malikk-habib-ur-rehman).

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in your `viewdidload`

```
 Config.tabsToShow = [.videoTab]
```

it will help you to show videos only .... :)

Comment: When I tried this I am getting this "First 15 seconds"

Comment: Yes but I am not able to select multiple videos and also showing "First 15 seconds"

Comment: its strange you have to research the dreamworld properly https://github.com/hyperoslo/Gallery/issues