# Total upload count is 0 when uploading file to Firebase using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'd like to show users a progress bar when uploading video files recorded within an iOS app to Firebase, so I'm using the `observeStatus` feature of the SDK:

```
// Create a root reference
FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [_storage reference];

// Create a reference to the video
FIRStorageReference *videoRef = [storageRef child:uuidString];

// Upload the file
FIRStorageUploadTask* uploadTask = [videoRef putFile:url metadata:nil];

[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusProgress handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
    // A progress event occurred
    double percentComplete = 100.0 * (snapshot.progress.completedUnitCount) / (snapshot.progress.totalUnitCount);

    NSLog(@"Video with ID %d recording upload progress: %f, completed unit count %lld, total unit count %lld", video.videoId, percentComplete, snapshot.progress.completedUnitCount, snapshot.progress.totalUnitCount);
}];
```

However, 'Total Unit Count' always seems to be 0, meaning the calculated percent complete goes a bit bonkers with the whole divide-by-0 situation:

```
Video with ID 3 recording upload progress: inf, completed unit count 163922, total unit count 0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Following the docs as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#full_example).

[Replicated also in Swift]

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually create the `NSProgress` correctly, and update it appropriately for in memory uploads (`putData`), but aren't getting the file size for file uploads (`putFile`) since apparently I didn't discover file attributes/they weren't always correct.

I'm working on a fix shortly, for now you can use the `NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(url.path!)[NSFileSize]!.longLongValue` workaround to get the file size :)

EDIT (10/10/16): this has been resolved, and if you use the latest version of Firebase Storage, you won't have this problem :)

Comment: it didn't work for me. it gives %25 at max. completedUnit and fileSizes doesn't seem to be same "units". ideas?

Comment: it seems fixed now.

Comment: Yep, this was fixed a few months ago--sorry for not updating this.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Using `data` upload is working fine:

```
    NSData *data = // ... some real data to upload

    FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [storage referenceForURL:@"gs://<YOURPATH>"];

    // Upload the file to the path
    FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask = [storageRef putData:data metadata:nil completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata * _Nullable metadata, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            // Error handle it
        } else {
            NSString *urlToDownload = metadata.downloadURL;
        }

    }];

    // Add a progress observer to an upload task
    [uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusProgress
                          handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
                              // A progress event occurred
                              double percentComplete = 100.0 * (snapshot.progress.completedUnitCount) / (snapshot.progress.totalUnitCount);
                              NSLog(@"\n\nloading...%f",percentComplete);
                          }];
```

I hope this can help either OP or anyone else.

Comment: I can certainly give it a go, but thinking it might not resolve the issue as the "completed unit count" figure increases as expected during the upload in the log trace.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately this is the correct behavior: data has a length property which we can grab the "file size" off, while URLs don't have a similar mechanism (you have to dive through a few layers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743856/finding-files-size). Will fix this soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer either of us want but I am guessing there's a bug in the Firebase SDK where it's not creating the `NSProgress` instance correctly.

So, as a work around you can capture the file size before you create the upload task. I am using this extension (which is super crashy with the IUOs for convenience sake).

```
extension NSFileManager {
    func fileSize(atUrl url: NSURL) -> Int64 {
        return try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(url.path!)[NSFileSize]!.longLongValue
    }
}
```

Capture the file size value and use that in place of `totalUnitCount` in your calculation.

FWIW I filed a bug for this issue at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/